# Replicate std::function or boost::function?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, c++11, boost, pointer-to-member, c++03

How can I replicate `std::function` or `boost::function`?

I am compiling with **C++03** and I am actively **avoiding boost**.

This started with me trying to treat class methods as regular function pointers. [I learned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24014898/function-method-pointers-pushed-to-a-deque) about `std::function` and `boost::function` from that endeavour.

Comment: Boost function was around long before C++11, and the source code is readily available.  Reading it will be educational (and helpful).

Comment: Considering your limitations, are you sure that you need std::function?

Comment: It can be a painful process because of Boost's internal dependencies, but it should be possible to isolate the required pieces of Boost and copy them alongside your code.

Comment: You don't need to install anything, as the relevant Boost parts are header-only. Use [BCP](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0b1/tools/bcp/doc/html/index.html)  to extract headers needed by `boost::function`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a pre C++11 function pointer to a member function with a declaration like this:

```
ReturnType (ClassType::*func_ptr)() = &ClassType::function;
```

and call it using *an instance* of the class with `(instance.*func_ptr)()`. E.g.

```
struct Foo {
    bool memberFunc() { return true; }
};

int main() {
    typedef bool (Foo::*member_func_t)();      // Typedef member func pointer type.
    member_func_t func_ptr = &Foo::memberFunc; // Declare function pointer.
    Foo foo;                                   // Create foo object.
    (foo.*func_ptr)();                         // Call member func using instance.
}
```

There is a way to recreate the generic properties you are looking for ([I read your other question too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24014898/function-method-pointers-pushed-to-a-deque)) if you only need to create pointers to *member functions*. It will not work if you mix in non-member function pointers.

By using templates and a wrapper class deriving from a common non-template base class you can wrap a member function pointer pointing to a function that is a member of *any* class type. The base class creates a common type independent of which class the wrapped function pointer is a member of. This can be useful if you e.g. want to store the wrappers in the same container.

This example will work as long as the function signature is always the same (in this case it's fixed as `bool()`).

```
struct func_base {
    virtual ~func_base() {};
    virtual bool operator()() const = 0;
};

template <typename C>
class func_wrapper : public func_base {
public:
    typedef bool (C::*member_func_ptr_t)();
    func_wrapper(member_func_ptr_t func_ptr, C* instance_ptr)
        : m_func_ptr(func_ptr), m_instance_ptr(instance_ptr) {}
    bool operator()() const { return (m_instance_ptr->*m_func_ptr)(); }
private:
    member_func_ptr_t m_func_ptr;
    C* m_instance_ptr;
};
```

You can also create a helper function to create wrappers which automatically deduces the member type.

```
/* This function returns a pointer to dynamically *
 * allocated memory and it is thus the callers    *
 * responsibility to deallocate the memory!!      */
template <typename C>
func_base* make_wrapper(bool (C::*func_ptr)(), C* instance_ptr) {
    return new func_wrapper<C>(func_ptr, instance_ptr);
}
```

Now you can use it e.g. like this:

```
struct Bar { // Define some other class with member function.
    bool memberFunc() { return false; }
};

int main() {
    Foo foo; // Create object instances.
    Bar bar; // ----------||-----------

    std::deque<func_base*> d; // Deque storing pointers to base class.

    // Push pointer to any member func.
    d.push_back(make_wrapper(&Foo::memberFunc, &foo));
    d.push_back(make_wrapper(&Bar::memberFunc, &bar));

    for (std::deque<func_base*>::iterator it = d.begin(); it != d.end(); ++it) {
        (**it)(); // Call all functions in deque.
    }

    for (std::deque<func_base*>::iterator it = d.begin(); it != d.end(); ++it) {
        delete *it; // REMEMBER to destroy wrappers pointed to!!
    }
}
```

This will compile with C++03 compilers. See this **[live demo](http://ideone.com/8PrrKZ)** compiled with gcc 4.3.2.

Note: You could easily modify the wrapper class to instead store a copy of the instance if you should want that.

Comment: You are amazing; beautiful code. I wish this was posted 2 hours earlier than it was.

I tried so many things to get this working that it became apparent it would be quicker for me to rewrite the design. :( I have this for next time though.. Thank you a great deal for that!

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use TR1's function and bind headers:

```
#include <tr1/functional>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

struct AddX {
    template <typename> struct  result { typedef std::string type; };

    std::string operator()(int a, int b) const { 
        std::ostringstream oss;
        oss << (a + b);
        return oss.str();
    }
};

int main() {
    using namespace std::tr1;

    function<std::string(int)> foo = bind(AddX(), 999, placeholders::_1);

    return foo(1).length();
}
```

Comment: cannot find this header

Comment: @JoshC Mmm. In that case, let this serve as inspiration (I hard code the signature, mostly because no variadics means a lot of red-tape code for the general case): http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ff95cf20dcbdf8a9